# Change storage directory in Artifactory

Tags: artifactory

I have just installed Artifactory and I need to set up and running a company-wide Ivy repository.

For disaster-recovery purposes, I need Artifactory to store data on a RAID-1 file system mounted at `/srv` (where MySQL datafiles are stored also). I would not prefer using blob storage, so how can I tell Artifactory to store all of its data in a directory different than the standard?

System info: I run SLES 11 and I have installed Artifactory from RPM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have artifactory 4.6 or greater, you can create a `$ARTIFACTORY_HOME//binarystore.xml` config file. e.g `/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc/binarystore.xml`

The following config would put the artifacts in the `/data` directory

```
<config version="v1">
    <chain template="file-system">                                <!-- Use the "file-system" template -->
    </chain>
    <provider id="file-system" type="file-system">                    <!-- Modify the "file-system" binary provider -->
            <fileStoreDir>/data/binaries</fileStoreDir>        <!-- Override the <fileStoreDir> attribute -->
    </provider>
</config>
```

Answer (score 5):

The checksum based storage is one of the biggest advantages of Artifactory. It gives much better performace, deduplication and allows uploads optimization, replication optimization, free copy and move artifacts. The blob storage is by far the right way to store blobs (binaries).

Location of the artifacts storage can be changed according your needs by mapping the storage as `$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/data`.

For disaster recovery we recommend to setup [active/passive synchronization or active/active cluster](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Clustering+Artifactory). Also, the [Artifactory backup](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Backups) dumps the files in the standard directory structure format and the location of the backup can be configured.

Comment: Can I change somewhere in the config file the path $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/data to be something else? Like /opt/nas/artifactory

Comment: @dmitry-r symlink to the rescue.

Comment: Is symlink still the recomended solution? Artifactory 4.6 introduced binarystore.xml https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+the+Filestore also this jira: https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-6282